# angular js drop down value order change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to change drop down value order. this is my drop down

```
<select ng-model="reportSearch.charityId">
    <option value="">--- All Charity ---</option>
    <option  ng-repeat="item in charityList | orderBy:'+value'">
      {{item.value}}
    </option> 
</select>
```

this is the my demo. in my demo i need to 'Engagement1 Name' show as the 5th option in the drop down. how  i change that order.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhLme0hj/)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by the `key`.

```
<option  ng-repeat="item in charityList | orderBy:'+key'">{{item.value}}</option>
```